# Shellcode Injection/Poisoning on Mobile Networks[GSM/LTE/CDMA-varaints]?

Tags: network, phone, shellcode, simcard

In the previous question([How do APN hacks work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145985/how-do-apn-hacks-work)) I have enquired about APN hacks but after reseaching more about cellular networks.
I wonder has anybody attempted Remote-code execution/poisoning,etc through packet interchange between cell and tower for identification/registration/etc purposes..

You may raise question that machines can be different but I guess big corporates are not keen on using different architectures they may use a particular standardized architecture ,passing *reliability test* ,though manufactured by different vendors ,icing on the cake is hardware updates are quite infrequent and there will be many technical debts aka bugs out there?

So has anybody attempted this in past?

Any specific technique  similiar to the intention of my question?